# suggestions on query to get counts from other tables on a postgres db

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to create a query that returns a list of members with counts from two secondary tables.

I have the members table with multiple members that share the same parent_id.

I have two other tables that for each member has multiple entries. The results i am trying to produce is a list of members for a particular parent_id and for each member a count of records from table2 and table3

The result would look like

member_id, parent_id, name, count(table2.member_id ), count(table3.member_id)

thanks for any help

```
table members

member_id   int primary key
parent_id   int  
name        varchar


table 2    ( member_id will have multiple records for each member )

t2_id      int primary key
member_id  int
data_2     int


table 3    ( member_id will have multiple records )

t3_id      int primary key
member_id  int
data_3     int
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use correlated subqueries:

```
select m.*,
       (select count(*) from table2 t2 where t2.member_id = m.member_id
       ) as num_t2,
       (select count(*) from table3 t3 where t3.member_id = m.member_id
       ) as num_t3
from members m;
```